# Select a row along with its next and previous rows

Tags: mysql, optimization

Situation:

At the moment I have 3 queries:

1. First - Gets data by id which has ordering position;
2. Second - Gets data by position-1;
3. Third - Gets data by position+1.

I want to have only 1 Query which could take "needed one" by id + previous and next ones if they exists.

Queries:

First

```
set @position = 0;

SELECT 
`position` FROM
(
  SELECT `id`, @position:=@position+1 as `position` FROM {#table}          
  "other_part_of_query"
  ORDER BY `modified_time` DESC
) t
WHERE 
t.id = '".id."' 
LIMIT 1
```

Second and third

```
set @position = 0;

SELECT 
`id` FROM
(
  SELECT `id`, @position:=@position+1 as `position` FROM {#table}          
  "other_part_of_query"
  ORDER BY `modified_time` DESC
) t
WHERE 
t.`position` = '".position."' 
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated, because you are selecting a row by `id`, but choosing the adjacent ones by another field, `modified_time`.

The idea is to use variables to enumerate the rows.  And, use another row to calculate the value for the `id` that you care about.  Do this in a subquery, and then select the rows that you want:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT `id`,
              @rn := if(@rnid := if(t.id  = '".id."', @rn + 1, @rnid),
                        @rn + 1, @rn + 1
                       ) as rn
      FROM {#table} t       
           "other_part_of_query" cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @rnid := 0) vars
      ORDER BY `modified_time` DESC
     ) t
WHERE rn in (@rnid - 1, @rnid, @rn)
```

Comment: I'm back. I'm getting - error: "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)".

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra conditions in your where clause to solve this. Consider the following three conditions:

- One row must have the modified_time you want.
- One row must have the maximum modified_time that is still less than the one you want. (The previous position)
- One row must have the minimum modified_time that is still greater than the one you want. (The next position)

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE modified_time = @myParam
   OR modified_time = (SELECT MAX(modified_time ) FROM myTable WHERE modified_time < @myParam)
   OR modified_time = (SELECT MIN(modified_time ) FROM myTable WHERE modified_time > @myParam);
```

Comment: Can't do that. All results must be ordered by "modified_time". That is why I'm using "set @position".
Also at first i have only id and I don't have position.

Comment: @RomanLosev If you replace my parameter with `modified_time` it should still get the values you want. I misread your queries. That is, as long as I still understand you want an event that happened at a specific time, as well as the most recent event before it and the next event after it?

Comment: Can't do that either. It was my first solution to get position. Problem is that some "datas" has same modified_time. And on pressing next next... sometimes it jumps 2 or even more positions.

Comment: @RomanLosev hmm. What about making it `WHERE modfiedTime <= @myParam`?

Comment: @RomanLosev any chance you can add some sample data to the question if you still aren't able to get it to work?

Comment: I'm trying Gordon Linoff suggestion atm

Answer (score 0):

Selecting next and previous rows of a specific row

```
SET @j = 0;
SET @i = 0;
SELECT *
FROM ( 
    SELECT id, col1, col2, ..., @j:=@j+1 AS pos
    FROM `table`
    WHERE  col1=... ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC
) AS zz
WHERE (    
    SELECT position
    FROM ( 
        SELECT id AS id2, @i:=@i+1 AS position
        FROM `table`
        WHERE  col1=... ORDER BY col1 DESC, col2 ASC
    ) AS zz
    WHERE id2=$currId
)
IN (pos-1, pos, pos+1)
```